# npm - EPERM: operation not permitted on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bower, npm-install

I ran

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

After running that command,
When trying to run any npm commands on Windows OS I keep getting the below.

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local'
at Error (native)
```

Have deleted all files from

```
C:\Users\<your username>\.config\configstore\
```

It did not work.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Running `npm cache clean --force` solved the issue for me.

Comment: Running npm cache clean --force for two times worked for me.

Comment: Did you run it in the `cmd.exe` "terminal" (command prompt) or from the `GitBash` terminal? For me, it failed when I ran it in `GitBash` but worked fine when I ran it in `cmd`.

Comment: Today I got EPERM even in `cmd.exe`. But I ran the following command standing in `C:\Program Files\nodejs`, and it seems to have worked: `npm cache clean --force && npm install <package-name> --force --global`. I also added `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules` to my system `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Screen-dump: https://i.imgur.com/VLFS7lG.png. But it might be a good idea to try https://stackoverflow.com/a/44014485 first.

Comment: I'd tried all these answers and none worked. Later, I installed a [Linux sub-system (WSL) in windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), and I never faced this issue again.

Comment: Try running the cmd as administrator

Comment: In my case, I had it working previously, and at some point when switching projects, it somehow gave me this error. I tried clearing the cache and followed some introduced fixes below, but none worked. I restarted my PC and it works like a charm.

Sometimes because we are now too technical and experienced we manage to overlook the most basic fix there is. :)

Comment: Just a note to my future self, Apache was blocked npm from spitting out build output to the htdocs folder. Stopping Apache fixed the issue.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Running this command was my mistake.

> npm config set prefix /usr/local

Path `/usr/local` is not for windows. This command changed the prefix variable at `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local'`

To access and make a change to this directory I need to run my cmd as administrator.

So I did:

1. Run cmd as administrator
2. Run `npm config edit` (You will get notepad editor)
3. Change `prefix` variable to `C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Then `npm start` works in a normal console.

Comment: In my case, I simply uncommented `prefix` (was `;prefix...`) after `npm config edit`, and Profit. Not sure if that's A Smart Thing, but it worked.

Comment: in my case I had no admin rights to me on the laptop so here's how I did it-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57249779/10603466

Comment: Just re-running as admin fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After searching a lot to what was causing the issue, your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 82):

This is occurring because windows is not giving permission to the user to create a folder inside system drive. To solve this:

Right Click

The Folder > **Properties** > **Security** Tab

Click on **Edit** to change Permissions > Select the user and give **Full Control** to that user.

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Granting the user access to change system folders is not a good idea, especially when this can be easily fixed by changing the prefix to a folder in the user's home directory.

Comment: this will not work with a company laptop where you are not the system admin.

Comment: In our case we have full control but folder was hidden. If you have already full control then check hidden option of the folder.

Comment: This answer worked for me, I gave the **Full Control** permissions to **Users** from the Security tab of the folder properties

Comment: The equivalent to this on a build server would be `attrib -R "C:\...\wwwroot\*.*" /S /D` (TFS makes everything Read-Only when checked out).

Comment: Works for me, thanks. I'm confused why D:\nodejs\node cache(this folder is created by me) is default not write permission, so i run 'npm install express -g' it shows error: ERROR EPERM mkdir operation not permitted.

Comment: Changing permissions on folders works for me (running powershell as an administrator doesn't work)

Answer (score 61):

Sometimes, all that's required is to stop the dev server before installing/updating packages.

Comment: how odd but true... installing react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0 for trying out react hooks didn't work until trying this

Comment: To add to this, if you suspect this issue is your dev server running but don't know how to stop it, just logout / restart your windows will always fix this lool

Comment: This is odd, can someone explain *why* this happens?

Answer (score 44):

**Restarting VsCode** solved it for me!

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me. For anyone else reading this, maybe try clearing and restarting your vscode terminal in case it caches the previous commands.

Comment: I'm fairly upset that I spent 30 mins on this.

Comment: VS Code seems to put its hooks into things that does not allow `npm i` to work properly.

Answer (score 27):

I recently had the same problem when I upgraded to the new version, the only solution was to do the downgraded

To uninstall:

```
npm uninstall npm -g
```

Install the previous version:

```
npm install npm@5.3 -g
```

Try update the version in another moment.

Comment: Exactly, I'm following this [topic](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18380) to know when it will be fixed.

Answer (score 22):

I use Windows 10.
I started the CMD as administrator, and it solved the problem.

Find CMD, right click, and click open as administrator.

Comment: @EtienneGautier That's... simply not true at all. What's your proposed solution for modifying system files? If there's any way to do it _other than_ with "administrator permissions" then there's something seriously wrong with the OS's security.

Comment: Hey @Clonkex, I was assuming that the context was NPM's one (according to the question). Still my comment is not relevant, I'm deleting it. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @EtienneGautier Ah fair enough.

Answer (score 21):

I had an outdated version of `npm`. I ran a series of commands to resolve this issue:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then:

```
npm install -g npm@latest --force
```

Then (once again):

```
npm cache clean --force
```

And finally was able to run this (installing Angular project) without the errors I was seeing regarding `EPERM`:

```
ng new myProject
```

Comment: As of npm@5 it is recommended if you use ```npm cache verify``` AKA a self healing mechanism ; which will ensure everything is consistent

Comment: Thanks brother, it works for me. I was trying to create a react application.

Answer (score 16):

In my case, I was facing this error because my directory and its file were opened in my editor (VS code) while I was running `npm install`. I solved the issue by closing my editor and running `npm install` through the command line.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem when I tried to install the npm package `AVA`. The solution for me was to delete the node_modules folder and force-clean the npm cache:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean --force
```

I could then install the npm package without a problem.

Comment: Yes, I somehow was having node_modules folders in the current working directory. It was throwing that exception when I tried to run angular cli commands 'ng new..'. Deleting node_modules folders helped.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, after updating npm. Solved it by re-installing latest npm again with:

```
npm i -g npm
```

but this time with cmd running in administrating mode.

i did all this because i suspected there was an issue with the update, mostly some missing files.

Answer (score 11):

## The Problem I faced (In Windows Computer)

When I was trying to install a couple of **npm** packages I got the following error:

**npm - EPERM: operation not permitted** - while *npm* was trying to rename a file

Here's my debug snippet for reference, if you've faced the similar problem:

[image: The Problem I faced]

After carefully checking out the answers from other users, I have created a detailed answer for the community

### My Solution for the problem

Follow the mentioned steps

1. Right-click on the project folder
2. Go to `properties -> Security Tab`
3. Select `Users -> Edit`
4. In the `Permission for Users` section, `Full control` -> `Give a check mark in Allow` -> `OK`
5. Wait for Windows security to apply the new security rules
6. Click `OK`

#### Visualization of the steps

[image: Change Security rules]

If you follow these steps and try to install npm packages again it will work properly.

**Note**: It's a best practice to close and open up the **command line** again to experience the changes

Answer (score 8):

for me it was an issue of altering existing folders in node_module, so i nuked the whole folder and run npm install again. it works with no errors after that

Answer (score 5):

Just run cmd as admin. delete old node_modules folder and run npm install again.

Comment: npm install should work without starting CMD as admin. It is not working on normal cmd(non admin) is also an issue.

Answer (score 5):

Happened to me since the folder/file was locked by another process. Used a tool (LockHunter) to terminate that process and it started working again (possible reason).

Comment: Mine was google drive somehow got my git folder set to sync, remove it and worked for me

Answer (score 4):

## Simplest way

Hope I am not too late for this post but recently even I too got hit by this issue. And also I had no admin rights on my laptop.

Here is the simplest way I fixed the bug.

1. Locate the file name `.npmrc` (it will be in `C:\Users\<user name>\.npmrc`)
2. Open it and change the path of `prefix=` to `prefix=C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\npm`

hope it will be helpful..

Answer (score 4):

This error is caused by different problems try the below one of them will work for you!

- try to run `npm` as Administrator
- Run cmd as administrator `npm config edit` (You will get notepad editor)
  Change `Prefix` variable to `C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Roaming\npm`
- The errors went after I disabled my anti-virus (Avast)
- Sometimes a simple cache clear like the below would fix it.

  ```
   npm cache clear
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Running npm commands in Windows Powershell solved my issue.

Comment: I was working on my company laptop, on which I regularly face some or the other issues with proxy or some security thing. I tried many things mentioned here and finally did this and it worked for me. But, not sure if doing this alone will be enough.

Answer (score 3):

If you getting this error in an IDE's terminal/commands prompt, try delete node_modules, close IDE, and run the `npm install` command again.
The time when IDE started but still not completed its analysis of node_modules tree is a tricky moment, when packages installation may fail because IDE still scanning node_modules contents.

Answer (score 3):

```
npm install cross-env
```

Try this it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

A reboot of my laptop and then

`npm install`

worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem come from bash terminal. I change my terminal to powershell and it's ok.

Really easy to resolve

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While circumventing the problem (by using another terminal) may be useful, I would much rather understand the problem and how to actually resolve it (in any terminal). In my case, the error occurs regardless of whether its executed in Git Bash (mingw64), cmd.exe, or PowerShell. (Oddly, running as administrator caused a different error message to result, but that might be irrelevant.)

Answer (score 2):

My only solution for this issue was changing the directory of the project (using Window OS). Initially was stored to `C:/`. when I move to `C:\Users\test\Desktop` started to work.

Answer (score 1):

Find this command `npm cache clean` as a solution to those error in quick and simple way!

Answer (score 1):

I updated my node version to 8.9.4 and ran the necessary install command again from administrator command prompt. It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Try npm i -g npm . NPM version  6.9 is work to me.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently **anti-virus software** can also cause this error.  In my case I had Windows Security's Ransomware Protection protecting my user folders which caused this error.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10,

Running the IDE (in my case IntelliJ) in administrator mode and executing npm install does resolves the problem.

If no IDE then run CMD in administrator mode and try executing npm install

Answer (score 1):

**For those trying to update config**

If having trouble updating your npm config, try instead running using the **-g flag**. This solved the issue on Win 10 for me after trying everything else.

```
npm config edit -g
```

I am able to update the config and changes are reflected everywhere.  This may be due to  running npm in an organizational scope.

Answer (score 1):

I was running create-react-app server. Simply stopped the server and everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

At least I just solved my problem in this way:

1. Search `cmd`
2. Then run as administrator
3. Then `npm i -g expo-cli` or `npm config set prefix /usr/local`

I just solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing it globally first, using the command
{npm install -g create-react-app}

And then, you can create your app using the command,
{npx create-react-app }

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Just `stop` react server and then install the package.

This issue occurs because when react is running (with `yarn start` or `npm start`), It is using some resources.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, as I was using my company LAN. And I just ran `cmd.exe npm` and I was able to execute my other commands without any error after that.

```
C:\Users\586656>cmd.exe npm
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Just sharing this, as it may help other folks who try to do this in their office LAN. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install npm package by running CMD as Administrator. you can headover to broad discussion on this bug at [npm install throwing error EPERM](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10826).

Answer (score 0):

Same to me,
My solution was close Android studio, AVD Manager, Visual Studio and reinstall.
I executed this command to update my expo cli:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, It was an issue with the .npmrc file. Which is present in C:\Users\myname.npmrc
Somehow the content of .npmrc file got changed. I have changed the content by comparing with my colleagues laptop. So it solved.

For reference, I am adding the content of .npmrc file too

```
 ;;;;
 ;npm userconfig file
 ;this is a simple ini-formatted file
 ;lines that start with semi-colons are comments.
 ;read `npm help config` for help on the various options
 ;;;;

 //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=95632bcf-3056-4538-b57d-38426736e3a0
 scope=true
 @true:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/

 ;;;;
 ;all options with default values
 ;;;;
 ;access=null

 ;allow-same-version=false

 ;always-auth=false

 ;also=null

 ;audit=true

 ;audit-level=low

 ;auth-type=legacy

 ;before=null

 ;bin-links=true

 ;browser=null

 ;ca=null

 ;cafile=undefined

 ;cache=C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

 ;cache-lock-stale=60000

 ;cache-lock-retries=10

 ;cache-lock-wait=10000

 ;cache-max=null

 ;cache-min=10

 ;cert=null

 ;cidr=null

 ;color=true

 ;depth=null

 ;description=true

 ;dev=false

 ;dry-run=false

 ;editor=notepad.exe

 ;engine-strict=false

 ;force=false

 ;fetch-retries=2

 ;fetch-retry-factor=10

 ;fetch-retry-mintimeout=10000

 ;fetch-retry-maxtimeout=60000

 ;git=git

 ;git-tag-version=true

 ;commit-hooks=true

 ;global=false

 ;globalconfig=C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc

 ;global-style=false

 ;group=0

 ;ham-it-up=false

 ;heading=npm

 ;if-present=false

 ;ignore-prepublish=false

 ;ignore-scripts=false

 ;init-module=C:\Users\myname\.npm-init.js

 ;init-author-name=

 ;init-author-email=

 ;init-author-url=

 ;init-version=1.0.0

 ;init-license=ISC

 ;json=false

 ;key=null

 ;legacy-bundling=false

 ;link=false

 ;local-address=undefined

 ;loglevel=notice

 ;logs-max=10

 ;long=false

 ;maxsockets=50

 ;message=%s

 ;metrics-registry=null

 ;node-options=null

 ;node-version=10.15.2

 ;offline=false

 ;onload-script=null

 ;only=null

 ;optional=true

 ;otp=null

 ;package-lock=true

 ;package-lock-only=false

 ;parseable=false

 ;prefer-offline=false

 ;prefer-online=false

 ;prefix=C:\Program Files\nodejs

 ;preid=

 ;production=false

 ;progress=true

 ;proxy=null

 ;https-proxy=null

 ;noproxy=null

 ;user-agent=npm/{npm-version} node/{node-version} {platform} {arch}

 ;read-only=false

 ;rebuild-bundle=true

 ;registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/

 ;rollback=true

 ;save=true

 ;save-bundle=false

 ;save-dev=false

 ;save-exact=false

 ;save-optional=false

 ;save-prefix=^

 ;save-prod=false

 ;scope=

 ;script-shell=null

 ;scripts-prepend-node-path=warn-only

 ;searchopts=

 ;searchexclude=null

 ;searchlimit=20

 ;searchstaleness=900

 ;send-metrics=false

 ;shell=C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe

 ;shrinkwrap=true

 ;sign-git-commit=false

 ;sign-git-tag=false

 ;sso-poll-frequency=500

 ;sso-type=oauth

 ;strict-ssl=true

 ;tag=latest

 ;tag-version-prefix=v

 ;timing=false

 ;tmp=C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp

 ;unicode=false

 ;unsafe-perm=true

 ;update-notifier=true

 ;usage=false

 ;user=0

 ;userconfig=C:\Users\myname\.npmrc

 ;umask=0

 ;version=false

 ;versions=false

 ;viewer=browser

 ;_exit=true

 ;globalignorefile=C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmignore
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything and nothing works.
Moving my working project folder to diffrent destination worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Likely when you experience this issue, it is possible is a permission issue on your PC. Going to the PC properties and granting which ever account you use on your PC **full control** will solve it.

Again command /usr/local doesn't work on windows

Answer (score 0):

If cleaning the cache(`npm cache clean --force`) doesn't help you just delete
manually the folder `C:\Users\%USER_NAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cacheand` and reinstall NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way to solve this by entering the below command

```
npm config set cache C:\tmp\nodejs\npm-cache --global
```

Answer (score 0):

**Install create-react-app**

I did not install create-react app. so I just run `npm install -g create-react-app` and the problèm was solved

Answer (score 0):

Incredibly, this happens when you are building your project, e.g.

> ng build myprojet

...and you are stood up inside the `dist/myprojet`, maybe withing the console. So you can easily close that console window or `cd ..` to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'd to update my npm using `npm-windows-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it had to do with the directory webpack was targeting to build the files. Somehow, the directory couldn´t be deleted, even if I would try to do it manually by windows explorer. So, you can either force delete through CMD or, as strange as it may sound, I closed my web browser that I was using to load the webpack compiled files and managed to get the directory deleted. Afterwards, I ran webpack again and worked. Maybe that was causing the directory dele block.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with this issue as well. Try updating Node to the latest version and then try the operation again. It may help you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31189140)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and tried all the given solutions and none of them worked.

I got it solved after adding package.json as there was no package.json file available in the folder where I was trying to install a module and faced the same error.

Give it a try maybe it helps someone

```
npm init

npm init all (skip configurations)
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing the command by specifying the version fixed it for me.

```
npm install --global npm@9.2.0
```

Unfortunately, neither did the restarting of the computer, executing `npm i -g npm@latest` or without `@latest`, executing `npm cache clean`/`verify` with or without respective `--force` argument, and even removing *npm* and *node_modules* folders and even providing access rights to the parent folder helped me.

Specifying the `npm` version worked.