# create-react-app, installation error ("command not found")

Tags: node.js, facebook, reactjs, npm

I have installed create-react-app exactly as instructed on the facebook instruction page (https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html):

> First, install the global package:
>
> `npm install -g create-react-app`

I did this. It appeared to work fine - the file was installed to

```
users/*name*/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/create-react-app
```

I'm not really sure why global install takes it to this path, but there you have it.

Next instruction:

> Now you can use it to create a new app:
>
> `create-react-app hello-world`

Couldn't be simpler, right? But Terminal spits out this at me:

```
-bash: create-react-app: command not found
```

It's probably something very simple I'm missing but I don't really know where to look. If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it!

**Note: I'm using Node v6.3.1, and npm v3.10.3**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your Node setup looks incorrect. It's not an issue with Create React App—it seems like you can't run any global Node commands.

It looks like `~/.node_modules_global/bin` is not in your `PATH` environment variable so it can't execute global commands. That's just how Bash works—it can't guess where the command lies, you need to tell it. I would assume Node installation should do this by default but it depends on how you installed Node.

So make sure that directory is in your `PATH` and try again. If you use Bash, add this to your `.profile` and then restart the Terminal:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.node_modules_global/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: FIxed! Thanks, that was just what I was after. Although there shouldn't be quotation marks around the filepath :)

Comment: Thanks for clarification!

Comment: Sorry, just one more question: although this worked, when I quit Terminal I have to repeat the process every time I reboot it. Is there a way of permanently changing the $PATH?

Comment: I don't intend to be *that guy*, but what if you don't want to install globally? I know this is the custom in Node, but whatever. Can you point at the `.node_modules` directory _within_ your project? Coming from Ruby, installing things so that they are available everywhere feels slightly _verboten_.

Comment: You don't need it in the future to be globally to *run* that project. The thing that created projects depends on *is* inside local `node_modules`. Your team members don't need to install CRA itself.

Comment: Installing it globally is fine because it almost never changes. There won't be dependency hell or anything because no projects will depend on it. It's just a command that creates a folder and runs npm install in it, letting a locally installed script take over. But if you insist on using zero global commands, yes, you can install CRA in some folder and run `node ./node_modules/.bin/create-react-app myapp` in that folder. It seems unnecessary though so I recommend against it.

Comment: @Paulos3000 Did my suggestion of putting it into `.profile` in your home directory work? That should execute when your Terminal starts.

Comment: Hi Dan, sorry I didn't manage to get that to work. It works when I do it temporarily - `export PATH=$HOME/.node_modules_global/bin:$PATH` - but I don't know how to access `.profile` through Terminal in order to make a permanent change to `$PATH`... can you help with this?

Comment: With my setup i.e Windows 10, Node v 6.7.0 , npm v 3.10.0, I could not find .node_modules_global folder.

However the executable create-react-app command was located under  `\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\npm` folder and adding it to system path variable worked for me.

Comment: In order to get node bin path use following command:"npm config get prefix"

Comment: Worked for `create-react-native-app` too

Answer (score 76):

You are able to apply the following solution:

```
$ npm config set prefix /usr/local
$ sudo npm install -g create-react-app
$ create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: This is helpful, using yarn,
yarn config set prefix /usr/local
sudo yarn global add create-react-app

Comment: I dont get why set a prefix to on npm will fix the pointing issue. where is prefix to be set on ?

Comment: Windows users beware: running `npm config set prefix /usr/local` might wreak havoc on your console, and you could end up with an `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted` error that will require you to follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows)

Comment: this is works on Big Sur. ( 11.2.1 (20D74) ) Thank you.

Comment: this broke my settings.  I believe my npm is installed locally.  Naturally doing the 1st command  breaks things.....how do I return to my default setting?  please consider me a newbie - especially dealiing with configs and all. thanks

Answer (score 38):

The environment variables are not set properly.
When you run the `create-react-app` it shows you a path along with the error. Copy that path and add it in the environment variable.

Alternatively you can use the command:

```
npx create-react-app <app_name>.
```

This will do the work for you.

Comment: Yea baby this works like charm.

Answer (score 11):

Try this. It worked or me. I found this in the React documentation. "Npx" is not a typo. It's a package runner tool that comes with npm 5.2+.

npx create-react-app my-app

Answer (score 6):

In 2020 Dec 17

Install Nodejs & npm

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt install npm
```

if you install maybe show you this like errors for Reactjs setup.this helpful for you

```
npm install -g create-react-app


npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2020-12-17T14_16_02_442Z-debug.log
```

then When you type after this

```
create-react-app test-react-app
```

Show you in terminal
zsh: command not found: create-react-app

you fix this error by using this command

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app test-react-app
```

I hope work fine for you also.

Answer (score 4):

Answers given above are right but I want to share some things that I also faced and these are basics.

#### To setup react project

If you want to create a node environment

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

(Sometimes we can also run without `sudo`; but sudo means install in system level.)

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodeenv

$ nodeenv env
$ source /bin/activate
```

If you want to create new react app then

```
$ npm install create-react-app
```

If an error occurs `create-react-app: command not found` then install with `-g`, it happens because node is installed globally and it is not getting the node in local

```
$ npm install -g create-react-app

$ create-react-app app_name
$ cd app_name
app_name$ npm start
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `npx` instead of `npm`.

Check this out-> https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app

Answer (score 2):

I hope you already installed Node package manager(npm).
now run `npm install -g create-react-app`, if everything fine then you can use `create-ract-app` command.
if you are getting any permission error just `sudo npm install -g create-react-app`.

I hope it will work.
Happy Hacking.

Answer (score 2):

if you face following this problem:

```
create-react-app: command not found
```

solution:

```
  sudo npx create-react-app react_spa
  cd react_spa
  sudo npm start
```

I hope its work.

Answer (score 2):

If above answers are not working, then try this

1. update the npm version (npm install npm@latest -g)
2. clear the cache (npm cache clean --force)
3. create the react project (npx create-react-app myapp)
   (while running the 3rd command, make sure that create-react-app is already installed in the pc)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I get it fixed.

1. Step # 1:- Make sure, Node js and React js is installed globally. You can check Nodejs by
   `node --version` . If not installed, install and run
   `export PATH=$HOME/.node_modules_global/bin:$PATH`
2. Step # 2:- Clean your npm cache by following the command
    `npm cache clean --force`
3. run
    `sudo npx create-react-app your-app-name`

And that's it. you're done.

**Please note, This solution worked for me for MAC OS**

Answer (score 1):

I tried all methods listed above and in other sites. They weren't working for me. But  for some reason I decided to **add** the **create-react-app directory** into my **system variables** as a last ditch method and to my surprise this actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Documentation
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

- Update Node & NPM
- npm init react-app my-app or npx create-react-app my-app
- cd my-app
- npm start

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar challenge but on running  the command

```
npm i tar
```

I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

**Note**: use **npx** instead of npm.

**Wrong Command**: npm install -g create-react-app *<app_name>*

**Correct Command**: npx install -g create-react-app *<app_name>*