# react-native not working (CLI and create-app) MacOS

Tags: node.js, bash, react-native, npm, macos-high-sierra

I installed Node.js directly from their site and `npm` and `node` are both up to date when running `npm -v`/`node -v`. I then typed `npm install -g create-react-native-app` and get the following:[image]

When running the command `npm install -g react-native-cli` it returns:[image]

When I try to create a react native app, it returns command not found (as expected) and I get the same thing when running `react-native init` [image]

I have tried uninstalling Homebrew, reinstalling it with node and npm and nothing seems to work (I currently have Homebrew uninstalled). Can anyone help me get React-Native working?! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try cache clean `npm cache clean --force
`

Comment: I ran that command and then `create-react-native-app app-name` and still got `command not found`

Comment: Then there might be some permission issues with your npm , try `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
` as mentioned in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16151707/6606831)

Comment: After I run that, do I run the `create-react-native-app` command?

Comment: Yes, that would reclaim your permissions, then after that it should fix the error.

Comment: Still received the command not found.

Comment: You might need to install it first if the package is not available, try `npm install <package>` and then run command

Comment: Well, that didn't show errors, but still ended up getting command not found

Comment: Are you doing this `npm install -g create-react-native-app` then `create-react-native-app codes` ? Simply try typing this `create-react-native-app` to check if it installed globally.

Comment: When I run `npm install -g create-react-native-app` it throws errors and `create-react-native-app` shows command not found. I have been at this for 2 days now and I am so lost and frustrated

Comment: Alright the last option would be to install using `sudo npm install -g create-react-native-app` and run command again.

Comment: Shows the package was installed, but still returns command not found 

Comment: Okay, one more thing try running `create-react-native-app` in a new terminal

Comment: Command not found. I honestly have no idea why it won't work

Comment: Run this in the terminal to set your home path correctly and `export PATH=$HOME/.node_modules_global/bin:$PATH
` run `create-react-native-app` again in new terminal

Comment: command not found (again!)

Comment: Seems wierd, last try would be to check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46879073/6606831) , just modify for `create-react-native-app`

Comment: That seemed to work! Thank you SOO much!!!