# Node Modules not Found Even Environment is Configured

Tags: node.js, windows, variables, environment

I am installing nodeJS v10 in Windows 10 Pro, After downloading the installer and install, I can run npm and npx to install the node modules but the installed global command cannot be found. I also try to use back `npm install -g`, but the error stays the same. Saying `react-create-app`, I can see it is being installed in the specified directory, but it always report command not found.

**Command not found**

[image]

`npm config get prefix`

[image]

Actual directory

[image]
[image]

**Environment variable settings**

User Variables

[image]

System Variables

[image]

As the environment variable seems setting up correctly, it is so weird for not finding the command. Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create-react-app, installation error ("command not found")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751830/create-react-app-installation-error-command-not-found)

Comment: I do think It appears to be the problem of environment variable set up, but I can't figure out where...Weird, the env var seems okay, and I can also see the path when I print `$PATH` in the terminal

Comment: 2 weeks and I still can't find any clues why global command is not found. The possible duplicated question is not my case as I can confirm the PATH environment includes the node modules installation directory. The only suspect is the path which contains spaces ('Jacky Lam')