# Unable to update webpack 1.5.2 to webpack 2.0.0 for reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-2015, webpack

I am using VS2015, React.js and webpack. I have installed all packages. but I have got webpack 1.5.2 in my system as default. I am trying to update webpack 2.0.0 but it do not allow me to update that package. it gives error like below :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GucaN.png

Here's Code of webpack.config.js file

```
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/app.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'appBundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" },
            { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader" },
            { test: /\.jpeg$/, loader: "file-loader" },
            { test: /\.gif$/, loader: "file-loader" },
            { test: /\.txt$/, loader: "raw-loader" },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" },
            { test: /.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=\.]+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            { test: /\.css$/,loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
        }, {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            test: /\.js$/,
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
            },
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css", {
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new webpack.OldWatchingPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Here is code of package.json

{

```
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack --watch --display-modules",
    "server": "browser-sync --port 5100 start --server --files \"**/*.html\" \"build/**/*.css\" \"build/**/*.js\" "
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
    "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.14.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "1.5.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-barcode": "^1.0.3",
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-charts": "^1.0.3",
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-gantt": "^1.0.2",
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-grid": "^1.0.9",
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-lineargauge": "^1.0.2",
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-mediaplayer": "^1.0.4",
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-pivotgrid": "^1.0.5",
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-qrcode": "^1.0.2",
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-radialgauge": "^1.0.2",
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-scheduler": "^1.0.3",
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-sparklines": "^1.0.2",
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-stockchart": "^1.0.4",
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-treelist": "^1.0.7",
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-treemap": "^1.0.4",
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-treeview": "^1.0.2",
    "kendo-ui-react-jquery-upload": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "webpack": "1.5.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: You've got Webpack in `dependencies` and `devDependencies` - you should only have the latter.

Comment: Not sure, but have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows) question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following command. It will install the latest stable version of webpack.

```
npm install --save-dev webpack@2.2.1
```

In addition, you may want to check webpack version from the command line or easily in `package.json`file..

```
npm view webpack version
```

Comment: I tried that command  but I have got version 1.5.2. Please if you have another way then please let me know.

Comment: `npm uninstall --save-dev webpack` and after that  run the command which is in the answer