# Npm Operation Not permitted issue

Tags: macos, npm, terminal

I am actually trying to run `sudo npm -g install bower` but my mac does not let me run anything that has npm on it. The error is

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir '/usr/ps2791'
```

See the picture below.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: can you provide what is output of command?

Comment: Included the picgture and extracted the error message textually. Please see the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for further tricks like this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using latest Mac OSX > 10.10? because all the MAC OSX has SIP enabled by default. In order to make use of npm command. Disable SIP on mac os.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34614939/187808) you might need to set the npm prefix to a directory that your user can actually fiddle with. I.e.

```
mkdir ~/npm_config
npm config set prefix ~/npm_config
```