# How to solve EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\AppData'

Tags: angularjs, npm, command-line-interface, npm-install, mkdir

When I install Angular, an error occurs:

```
Admin@Admin-PC MINGW32 ~
$ npm install -g @angular/cli
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\AppData'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
...
```

The error shows that, "operation not permitted". However, I'm sure that I do this with Admin authority.

I have never met this type of error, so I guess it tells me to do `mkdir 'C:\Users\AppData'` command. However, doing that command also meets a permission denial error as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows

Comment: @sachilaranawaka I had read that question already and did as the answer says, but it does not work.

Comment: Please add relevant, obvious details: `node --version`, `npm --version`, Windows version (Computer -> Properties), MinGw version. Also, not that the path mentioned in the error is special and should not be created. It should be `C:\Users\username\AppData`. Finally, why run this through MinGw at all? Use `cmd.exe` or `Powershell.exe`. And lastly try creating the thing directly in that situation...