# Angular2Fire Installation error

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-services, node-modules

Whenever I tried to install angular2 fire module using npm i get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "angularfire2" "firebase" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path E:\abcd\node_modules\.staging\base64url-fd6cd85c
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'E:\abcd\node_modules\.staging\base64url-fd6cd85c' -> 'E:\abcd\node_modules\firebase\node_modules\base64url'
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
```

I am new to angular2 as well as firebase. whether I need to install polyfill module? or where I'm wrong?

Comment: Refer this url might be helpful,
[EPERM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows)

Comment: Cleared node_modules and installed again in local project as well in global. It works for me now