# What is the (ERR! code ENOLOCAL npm ERR!) Could not install because of an error?

Tags: json, windows, angular, npm

I am going to update `npm` latest version, but it's showing this error message:

```
G:\>npm i -g npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL npm ERR!
Could not install from "" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\hemanth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-08T03_34_29_774Z-debug.log
G:\>
```

[image: Error]

Comment: I was typing `-create-react-native-app` instead of `create-react-app` and it was the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 69):

This is an issue in node which is caused by white space in your windows username (possibly between the first-name and last-name in windows).

run the following command after replacing firstname with your windows user firstname in command prompt with administrator access

```
npm config set cache "C:\Users\Firstname~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global
```

Comment: I've had issues all the time due to my name folder having a space in it. I'm excited to see if I can utilize this solution to resolve issues with other tools as well (Rust, etc). Cheers!

Comment: Amazing, the solution worked immediately. Thanks!

Comment: Not that it looks like it's not always "Firstname~1" in that path. I needed to leave out the last letter of my first name: "Firstnam~1" (no, that's not my real name).

Comment: This solution works just fine, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 36):

This worked for me:

```
npm cache verify
```

Then I re-ran:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

And it installed like as expected: Issue resolved

[image: screenshot of terminal output]

Comment: You are the MVP!

Answer (score 12):

I got same issue because I was using an updated "package-lock.json" file from another system, and there was no "node_modules" folder on system where I got the problem.

You can try to following:

1. Move "package-lock.json" to some other folder, outside current directory.
2. npm install

Comment: Only solution that worked.

Answer (score 8):

If you are facing with this issue, first you should update npm using the below code:

```
npm -g install npm
```

then try to create the React file. It is working 100% for me.

Answer (score 3):

Run CMD in administrator mode and fire below commands in order

1. Run cmd as administrator
2. Run npm config edit (You will get notepad editor)
3. Change prefix variable to C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm
4. npm install -g create-react-app
   Go to the link for more [npm - EPERM: operation not permitted on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows?answertab=active#tab-top)
   Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
npm cache verify
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Answer (score 3):

I got error npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL while running npx create-react-app my-app
uninstall and install is worked for me…
npm uninstall -g create-react-app

npm install -g create-react-app
this will upgrade your npx, then run
npx create-react-app my-app
this works fine

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
npm install -g degit
```

is like an upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Please verify, whether your **npm** has installed **create-react-app** in 
**%AppData%Roaming\npm\node_modules**

if not then install it by using the command

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Windows, the firewall will block the `node.exe` to create `package.json`.

So turn off the firewall settings and try once. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem while trying to use sevelte with
the command

```
npx degit sveltejs/template youproject
```

The following was useful:

```
install -g degit
```

Answer (score -1):

Run `npm ci`.
Its works for me.