# npm-shrinkwrap.json: Could not install from "node_modules/react-navigation/react-native-tab-view@github:react-navigation/react-native-tab-view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-shrinkwrap

I tried to run an `npm install` this morning on a React Native 0.53.3 project with   `"react-navigation": "1.5.11",` and I got this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules/react-navigation/react-native-tab-view@github:react-navigation/react-native-tab-view#36ebd834d78b841fc19778c966465d02fd1213bb" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

I thought it would resolve by adding this to my `package.json` file:

```
"react-native-tab-view": "^1.3.2",
```

but I continue to get that same error. I opened a couple of issues with react-navigation team and it got closed as they concluded it is a problem with `npm`.

How can I resolve this?

It looks like it is referencing this inside of `npm-shrinkwrap.json`:

```
"react-native-tab-view": {
      "version": "github:react-navigation/react-native-tab-view#36ebd834d78b841fc19778c966465d02fd1213bb",
      "from": "react-native-tab-view@github:react-navigation/react-native-tab-view#36ebd834d78b841fc19778c966465d02fd1213bb",
      "requires": {
        "prop-types": "^15.6.0"
      }
    },
```

Comment: try `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install`. Seems a folder permission issue

Comment: @kushalvm, I continue to get the same error.

Comment: try deleting all lock files as well. `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` if there.

Comment: @kushalvm, I added a little more detail above. The error is referencing the `npm-shrinkwrap.json`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143945/err-code-enolocal-npm-err-could-not-install-from?rq=1

Comment: @kushalvm, interesting, I actually do not have a `package-lock.json` file to remove. I am wondering if I should just remove that `react-native-tab-view` from `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, but my concern with that is I also have that package inside of `yarn.lock` file.

Comment: No clue what `npm-shrinkwrap.json` is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194187/discussion-between-daniel-and-kushalvm).

Comment: Delete `react-native-navigation` and `react-native-tab-view` from `package.json`. and `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install`

Comment: @hongdevelop, I tried your recommendation and I get the same error, I am thinking I need to either remove that `react-native-tab-view` from `npm-shrinkwrap.json` first and if that does not work, remove `npm-shrinkwrap.json` altogether and just go with the `package-lock.json` convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with `npm-shrinkwrap.json` where the error kept referencing the following inside of it:

```
"react-native-tab-view": {
      "version": "github:react-navigation/react-native-tab-view#36ebd834d78b841fc19778c966465d02fd1213bb",
      "from": "react-native-tab-view@github:react-navigation/react-native-tab-view#36ebd834d78b841fc19778c966465d02fd1213bb",
      "requires": {
        "prop-types": "^15.6.0"
      }
    },
```

Removing just this did not help, I had to completely remove `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and do an `npm install` with just the conventional `package-lock.json`.