# troubleshoot angular project errors

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I was provided an angular project with a set of existing errors and a list of enhancements to work on. When I downloaded the same and tried running "npm install" on the project, it failed saying "Operation not permitted by operating system". I have tried all the solutions suggested online including:

1. npm cache clean
2. npm cache clean --force
3. deleting the node_modules folder
4. Running npm cache clean over and over again
5. Trying different versions of Node along with npm v5+
6. Running all the commands and opening IDE in "Run as Administrator" mode
7. Ran all the commands from command prompt as well
8. Ran all the commands from command prompt opened in "Run as Administrator" mode
9. Deleted the package-lock.json file and then ran "npm install"
10. Deleted the package-lock.json file and then ran "npm install --no-optional"
    In between all the above steps tried my own recipes as well.

If someone could help me figure out what the issue is?

I found a thread on Github discussing the error. The solutions described do not work for me.

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/853

Comment: That's a very unhelpful error message. I'm sure it was very frustrating. Do you still have the issue now? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, The below steps helped me resolve the issue.

Installed `material-design-icons` globally using `npm install material-design-icons -g`
Next, removed the `node_modules` directory from the project and ran `npm install`.
This worked for me but not in time to submit before deadline. The project compiled and ran successfully using `npm start` post the above steps.