# npx create-react-app my-app deleting installed node_modules package after creating?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, reactive-programming

When I start to create a new react app, and run -*npx create-react-app my-app*, I see after installing reactand other modules, it is deleting all file folder. Below is the code details found in cmd.

*...
├─ react-scripts@3.0.0
└─ react@16.8.6
Done in 422.17s.
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\lenovo.yarnrc'*

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd D:\test\project\react\my-app has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting my-app/ from D:\test\project\react
Done.

D:\test\project\react>

Screen-shot of Command line tool as
[CMD lines after create-new-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW7Wl.png)

System And version:
Windows10
node@10.15.3
npm@6.9.0
yarn@1.15.2
npx@6.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Check out the solutions provided for npm - EPERM: operation not permitted on Windows
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows)

If nothing works try downloading over different internet connection as well.

Comment: 1. Run cmd as administrator
2. Run npm config edit (You will get notepad editor)

************************************ getting below error

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm config edit
npm ERR! path C:\Users\lenovo\.npmrc
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\lenovo\.npmrc'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\lenovo\.npmrc']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open \'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\.npmrc\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,

Answer (score 0):

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

```sh
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
yarn global remove create-react-app
```

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/