# Angular 8: Getting internal/modules/cjs/loader.js error when i try to ng serve

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

When I clone my angular project and run "npm install" for installing all dependencies in node_module I face with this error:

```
npm ERR! path D:\Project\VipUi\angular\node_modules\.staging\echarts-25586c04\map\js\world.js
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\Project\VipUi\angular\node_modules\.staging\echarts-25586c04\map\js\world.js'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\Project\VipUi\angular\node_modules\.staging\echarts-25586c04\map\js\world.js']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\Project\VipUi\angular\node_modules\.staging\echarts-25586c04\map\js\world.js'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'lstat',
npm ERR!      path:
npm ERR!       'D:\\Project\\VipUi\\angular\\node_modules\\.staging\\echarts-25586c04\\map\\js\\world.js' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat \'D:\\Project\\VipUi\\angular\\node_modules\\.staging\\echarts-25586c04\\map\\js\\world.js\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'lstat',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    'D:\\Project\\VipUi\\angular\\node_modules\\.staging\\echarts-25586c04\\map\\js\\world.js',
npm ERR!   parent: 'angular' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
```

and I try to get node_module of  my teammate and copy it in my project I get the loader.js error in my powershell

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Project\VipUi\angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> [npm - EPERM: operation not permitted on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows)

1. Run cmd as administrator
2. Run npm config edit (You will get notepad
       editor)
3. Change prefix variable to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: for install node module

Comment: C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm its like this

Comment: C:\Users\Karim\AppData\Roaming\npm i add this

Comment: can i know your npm version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198570/discussion-between-orbit-and-karim).