# when I do npm install so terminal show me errors

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, react-redux

When I entered `npm install` so it take almost more than half an hour and shows me these errors. Please provide me some solutions for it.

> npm ERR! path E:\React Native\First
>   Practice\node_modules.staging\react-native-3ae3ca51\RNTester\RNTesterIntegrationTests\ReferenceImages\RNTester-js-RNTesterApp.ios\testScrollViewExample_1-iOS10_tvOS.png
>   npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! errno -4048 npm ERR! syscall unlink npm
>   ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'E:\React
>   Native\First
>   Practice\node_modules.staging\react-native-3ae3ca51\RNTester\RNTesterIntegrationTests\ReferenceImages\RNTester-js-RNTesterApp.ios\testScrollViewExample_1-iOS10_tvOS.png'
>   npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'E:\React Native\First
>   Practice\node_modules.staging\react-native-3ae3ca51\RNTester\RNTesterIntegrationTests\ReferenceImages\RNTester-js-RNTesterApp.ios\testScrollViewExample_1-iOS10_tvOS.png']
>   { npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'E:\React Native\First
>   Practice\node_modules.staging\react-native-3ae3ca51\RNTester\RNTesterIntegrationTests\ReferenceImages\RNTester-js-RNTesterApp.ios\testScrollViewExample_1-iOS10_tvOS.png']
>   { npm ERR!     errno: -4048, npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM', npm ERR!
>   syscall: 'unlink', npm ERR!     path: 'E:\React Native\First
>   Practice\node_modules\.staging\react-native-3ae3ca51\RNTester\RNTesterIntegrationTests\ReferenceImages\RNTester-js-RNTesterApp.ios\testScrollViewExample_1-iOS10_tvOS.png'
>   npm ERR!   }, npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not
>   permitted, unlink 'E:\React Native\First
>   Practice\node_modules\.staging\react-native-3ae3ca51\RNTester\RNTesterIntegrationTests\ReferenceImages\RNTester-js-RNTesterApp.ios\testScrollViewExample_1-iOS10_tvOS.png'",
>   npm ERR!   errno: -4048, npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM', npm ERR!   syscall:
>   'unlink', npm ERR!   path: 'E:\React Native\First
>   Practice\node_modules\.staging\react-native-3ae3ca51\RNTester\RNTesterIntegrationTests\ReferenceImages\RNTester-js-RNTesterApp.ios\testScrollViewExample_1-iOS10_tvOS.png'
>   npm ERR! } npm ERR! npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your
>   operating system. npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in
>   use (by a text editor or antivirus), npm ERR! or that you lack
>   permissions to access it. npm ERR! npm ERR! If you believe this might
>   be a permissions issue, please double-check the npm ERR! permissions
>   of the file and its containing directories, or try running npm ERR!
>   the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not
>   recommended).
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-31T17_33_47_718Z-debug.log

Comment: Why do you execute the command?

Comment: what is your npm version? `npm --version`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows

Comment: @matcheek my version is v12.9.1

Comment: @RohitKashyap it's not duplicate

Comment: Hence the word possible.

Comment: @ZaInKhAn The latest stable version of npm as of now is `v6.11.2`. You probably checked for `node` version and not `npm`. And seeing the errors a lot if is permission issue, u could try some of the suggestions given by @RohitKashyap SOA link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved. The issue is I haven't installed git that's why these errors born.