# Error creating new angular project using npm

Tags: node.js, angular, new-project

I am trying to create a new project using npm. It getting the following error. I have also tried opening the command prompt window 'Run as Administrator'. Still facing an issue.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "codeanal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.19",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.19",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

**Error:**

> ```
> 19889 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
> 19890 warn enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'D:\Angular\codeanal\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-952d5fc1'
> 19891 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> 19891 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
> 19892 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Angular\codeanal\node_modules\.staging\typescript-06d41b51\lib\lib.dom.d.ts'
> 19893 verbose cwd D:\Angular\codeanal
> 19894 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
> 19895 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--quiet"
> 19896 verbose node v12.13.0
> 19897 verbose npm  v6.12.0
> 19898 error code EPERM
> 19899 error syscall unlink
> 19900 error path D:\Angular\codeanal\node_modules\.staging\typescript-06d41b51\lib\lib.dom.d.ts
> 19901 error errno -4048
> 19902 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Angular\codeanal\node_modules\.staging\typescript-06d41b51\lib\lib.dom.d.ts'
> 19902 error  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Angular\codeanal\node_modules\.staging\typescript-06d41b51\lib\lib.dom.d.ts'] {
> 19902 error   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Angular\codeanal\node_modules\.staging\typescript-06d41b51\lib\lib.dom.d.ts'] {
> 19902 error     errno: -4048,
> 19902 error     code: 'EPERM',
> 19902 error     syscall: 'unlink',
> 19902 error     path: 'D:\\Angular\\codeanal\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-06d41b51\\lib\\lib.dom.d.ts'
> 19902 error   },
> 19902 error   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\\Angular\\codeanal\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-06d41b51\\lib\\lib.dom.d.ts'",
> 19902 error   errno: -4048,
> 19902 error   code: 'EPERM',
> 19902 error   syscall: 'unlink',
> 19902 error   path: 'D:\\Angular\\codeanal\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-06d41b51\\lib\\lib.dom.d.ts',
> 19902 error   parent: 'codeanal'
> 19902 error }
> 19903 error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
> 19903 error It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
> 19903 error or that you lack permissions to access it.
> 19903 error
> 19903 error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
> 19903 error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
> 19903 error the command again as root/Administrator.
> 19904 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm - EPERM: operation not permitted on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows)

Comment: Was your angular installed globally as administrator on your  system?

Comment: strange its working fine for me. Can you try to remove the node_module and the try?

Comment: are you sure that no angular dev-server is running and blocking the files?