# I am unable to create react app using npx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I am having a trouble on creating React app in my windows, I hope you guys can help me ..
I have wrote this command in hyper terminal 
`npx create-react-app new-app`
And I have checked my node.js version which is 12.16.1 and my npm version and npx version they both are 6.14.4.
I don't know why i am getting this error all the time

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Deepak'
command not found: create-react-app
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm - EPERM: operation not permitted on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows)

Comment: You can try to install it globally. `npm i -g create-react-app`, then simply run `create-react-app new-app`

Comment: Can you try these [steps to create a react project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122386/2873538)?

Answer (score 4):

Step-1

run following command

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

step-2

run following command

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: If we install the `create-react-app` globally then why should we use npx? There should be a better solution rather than installing package globally and then use them globally.

Comment: Hey Deepak, I’m having the same exact problem. Did you ever find a solution to this?