# I am trying to install npm package but its not working. Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\HAMZA~1'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install npm package but its not working. `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\HAMZA~1'`

I wrote this command,

```
$ npm install -g create-react-app
```

And it throws the following error:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\HAMZA~1
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\HAMZA~1'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\HAMZA~1'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\HAMZA~1'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\HAMZA~1'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   isOperational: true,
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\HAMZA~1'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

What does it mean? How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm - EPERM: operation not permitted on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

try running the "npm install" from a command prompt with Administrator rights.
in windows, look for it in the Accessories folder of the Start menu, or right click the start button and there will be an option to open a "Command Prompt (Administrator)" there.

in linux, use sudo...