# Why I am getting Error while starting with React?

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app, npx

I am new in React, and I have installed node and npm. Now, inside  Terminal, I am writing `npx-start create-react-app music-player`. But I am getting error

> *Error: EPERM: operation not permitted*

I am using Windows 10. I have put the image below of vscode.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: see it,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

### NPX

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

---

(npx comes with npm 5.2+ and higher, see instructions for older npm versions)

### NPM

```
nPm init react-app my-app
```

---

npm init  is available in npm 6+