# Uncaught Error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename ~~~

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

Q. I got this problem in my expo project. How can i solve this problem?

Uncaught Error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\예원.expo\state.json.1218894428' -> 'C:\Users\예원.expo\state.json'
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\KeywordAlarm
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c expo start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\예원\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-02-09T13_39_43_115Z-debug.log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm - EPERM: operation not permitted on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows)

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 5):

in my case, `npm cache verify` helped to solve this problem (win10, vs code)

Comment: This help's me, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Stop the project and try running `npm cache clean`. If that doesn't work, try `npm cache clean --force`.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to the mentioned directory (C:\Users[username].expo).
find state.json. duplicate it (state Copy.json) and *remove the previous version*. make sure the file name is state.json and voila.

try running npx expo login again.