# When I am installing expo on my pc, it is showing a error

Tags: react-native, npm-install, semantic-versioning, expo

**I have installed node on E dir and I am installing expo for react-native**

*E:>npm i -g expo-cli
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for semver@^7.3.5.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jca\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-05-03T05_32_28_520Z-debug.log*

**after this, when I am installing semver,**

*E:>npm install semver
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path E:

npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'E:'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'E:'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'E:\'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.*

Comment: Check if `node` is correctly installed and is added to your `Environment Variable` or not..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm - EPERM: operation not permitted on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows)

Comment: i have node version- 15.12.0