# I tried doing "npm install -g expo-cli" upon which I got a bunch of vulnerabilities. On "npm audit fix" i got the following more errors

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, windows-11

So, I've been working in node.js and react native before in Windows 10 without any issues. But ever since I started using this new laptop, with windows 11 in it, I get these annoying errors.
Doing `npm install -g npm@8.3.1` gave me the following result
[image]

so I did `npm audit fix` as suggested, on which I was greeted with this:

[image]

and so I did `npm i --package-lock-only`, again, as suggested. Which got me:
[image]

IDK what I'm doing wrong. I don't know how it'll affect me. Can someone help me understand this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can see from the path in your final screenshot that npm is trying to edit your `package-lock.json` file in the `C:\WINDOWS\System32` directory and does not have permission to do that.

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34614939/1700846) on how to update your npm configuration to use a folder that you do have permissions to write to.

Answer (score 1):

You have no problem executing `React-native` even if you do not perform the `npm audit fix` command

Also, you are not in the right position to do the command. The command must be executed in your project folder.