# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir

Tags: react-native, expo

I built an app in react native in Expo. After trying to make a build for google play store, I ran the command 'eas build --platform android' but I got the error saying ' Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir
'C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\eas-cli-nodejs\cbb3100e-c845-4dda-8e44-8c0d7f74b4b5-shallow-clone'
Code: EPERM'.

I have tried a lot of things but nothing works. I really need some help here.

Comment: I have changed the temp folder location from C drive to another drive but still getting the same issue

Comment: I'm stuck with this exact issues and have also tried 100 things. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Check your build 'dist' file there must be a 'Window-something' folder in it. I deleted that and npm install --legacy-peer-deps then it worked.

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows

Answer (score 4):

The problem can be temporarily solved by adding `"requireCommit": true` to eas-cli version in eas.json.
However, .easignore will be ignored if you let git control your workflow. May check if there are any empty directories inside your project as suggested by Anthony.

```
  "cli": {
    "requireCommit": true
  },
```

Source: https://forums.expo.dev/t/eas-0-44-1-internal-build-error-eperm/60930

Comment: Adding the `"requireCommit": true` did allow me to launch the build. After a long while, I got another error message:
```× Build failed
 Android build failed:
Unknown error. See logs for more information. ``` I don't know where the log file in questio is supposed to be...

Answer (score 2):

it cause by empty directory, please check the empty directory in project and delete it ..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer worked for me. It does not need any clarification :).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run this as Administrator. EPERM is a permissions issue.

Comment: I did try running as admin but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

adding "requireCommit": true to eas.json helped me.

Answer (score 0):

After making this configuration:

```
{
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.4.0",
    "requireCommit": true
  }
}
```

in my eas.json file, I pusblished the project to github. The compression and build process need the project published.This works for me.