# Next JS : Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open

Tags: reactjs, deployment, next.js, cpanel

I am trying to build the next Js app production files to deploy it on cPanel, when I execute
`npm run dev` the app is working just fine but as I start to build a production file with the help of this video(https://youtu.be/1ykSXau838c) and executes `npm run build` it gives me an error in the terminal as given below:

```
PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reactJs-project\NextJs\test-app> npm run build

> test-app@0.1.0 build
> next build

info  - Checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build .node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reactJs-project\NextJs\test-app\.next\trace'
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {    
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\reactJs-project\\NextJs\\test-app\\.next\\trace'
}
```

so I just want to know is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows

Comment: Are you currently running the app in dev? If yes, cancel that process and try to build it again. Most likely the build is not able to access the trace due to being open by the dev process.

Answer (score 37):

Posting comment from Koronag as an answer (as it helped me with this error and seems the most likely cause)...

This error is commonly seen when running a build while the dev server is already running.

E.g. in my case, I had a local build running via `npm run dev` and was trying to commit/push code, which invoked a Git Hook that also runs `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it works fine this answer drives me to the resolver.
I run 2 scripts in terminals:

- once for development
- another for the build process.

So after killing the development script it looks perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, npm run dev was running in another terminal. I closed that and rerun the command. It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

From next-sitemap repo README.md

"Having next-sitemap command & next-sitemap.js file may result in file opening instead of building sitemaps in windows machines.

As a solution to this, it is now possible to use a custom config file instead of next-sitemap.js. Just pass --config .js to build command."

[Next-Sitemap README.md - Building Sitemaps](https://github.com/iamvishnusankar/next-sitemap#building-sitemaps)

The above worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This also happen if your website is running on IIS. To run the dev server from terminal (code editor), stop the server on IIS and the error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the server development, and try to build again.
It works on me

Or if you want to force it (using Typescript) you can see on next docs right here https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/typescript

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35515670)