# npm install readline-sync node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080 throw err;

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to install npm readline but it's giving this error now and before it had given others

[image]

[image]

Deleted several folders and uninstalled nodejs but nothing helped
I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log messages, the npm agent appears to be facing issues in creating the necessary folders due to insufficient permissions.

As suggested by [@ratnez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5815842/ratnez) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37915233/1923688) you can grant the required permissions as follows:

1. Right Click The Folder > Properties > Security Tab
2. Click on Edit to change Permissions
3. Select the user and give Full Control to that user.