# Why are my Unity packages unresolved, every time I create a new project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, game-development, arcore, vuforia

I am continuously facing this error while creating a new Unity project. The temp file mentioned is not present in the package folder. If I continue with the creation of the project then I am unable to install more packages as it shows unresolved packages in the console.

An error occurred while resolving packages:
One or more packages could not be added to the local file system:
com.unity.ide.visualstudio: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Unity\cache\packages\packages.unity.com.tmp-11328-aMs3omsxMW9S\extract' -> 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Unity\cache\packages\packages.unity.com\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.18'

I tried reinstalling the Unity app and Unity hub as well. I cleared the cache and restarted the project as well but none of these seem to work. I need to download ARCore which is unable to be downloaded unless this error is resolved first.

Comment: Are you running the Hub as admin? Seems to be that the EPERM error code relates to your permission level when creating the new project

Comment: Also, take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows Similar problem, resolved by running the program with admin privileges