# "Unable to Initialize React App: Getting mkdir When Trying to Create a New React Application"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, npm, npx

C:\Program Files\React>npx create-react-app todoapp
node:fs:1378
const result = binding.mkdir(
^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\React\todoapp'
at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1378:26)
at module.exports.makeDirSync (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\make-dir.js:23:13)
at createApp (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:257:6)
at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:223:9
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
errno: -4048,
code: 'EPERM',
syscall: 'mkdir',
path: 'C:\Program Files\React\todoapp'
}

Node.js v21.5.0

Please solve me

Plaese help me to create react app

Comment: You're trying to create a new project in your Windows "Program Files" folder which is a (generally) system-protected folder - in other words you can't create a new folder in there. Create a new development folder under your Windows user account (`C:/Users/<accountname>`), and then create the project in that instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm - EPERM: operation not permitted on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows)