# nvim, rust-analyzer, EPERM: operation not permitted (on windows)

Tags: neovim, rust-analyzer, nvim-lspconfig

I am getting lots of EPERM without any apparent reason.

```
Error executing luv callback:
...ogram Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/_watch.lua:68: EPERM: operation not permitted: C:/Users/cesc/myproject/target/debug/deps/libserde_spanned-b6e765ece1d6a745.rlib.temp-archive-48e519c.a
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'assert'
    ...ogram Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/_watch.lua:68: in function <...ogram Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/_watch.lua:55>
```

Using nvim on windows :/.

```
NVIM v0.10.0-dev-2427+geb4783fb6
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.1.1707061634
Run ":verbose version" for more info
```

I already checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows) and changed permissions to full control but it didn't help.

Any ideas how can approach this to debug what the problem might be?

*Update 27-Feb-2024*: The issue seems to be related to `cargo build` running in the background while editing code.

Comment: I can provide my lsp config if necessary, but I believe it was s not relevant