# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Usr'

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

Everytime I try running a npm command on my school's computer it shows this error. If I try installing a package or create a vite project it will throw this error.

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Usr'

I looked at another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows) and it set to change the npm config but when I try doing that it throws the same error again. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What does `npm config list` show? Please [edit] your question to provide the details

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I still get the same error, `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Usr'`.

Comment: This is on a school computer as well, so I'm guessing that the config got changed at some point, and now because of how the computers have been setup I can't change it since I'm not admin. THis means that I need a way to somehow bypass the admin in this directory to change the file, so if anyone knows any commands I could run from powershell to do this then that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out now. For me, I had to locate the `.npmrc` file on my school's computer. Now the problem I faced is that it blocked out a bunch of locations and we could only access the `H:/` drive and not the `C:/` drive which is what was being shown in the error. To access the `C:/` drive I used this software I found on Github called [OpenArk](https://github.com/BlackINT3/OpenArk). Then I could access that drive and find the `.npmrc` file, and the file said that the prefix when to `C:/User` just like in the error, so I simply changed it to `H:/`.