npm install -g not working on windows even with run as administrator
I am trying to run npm i -g @nestjs/cli and corepack enable on a Windows machine.
I ran cmd as Administrator, as the image below indicates. Powershell as admin did not work too. I tried cleaning npm cache, it did not work.
Have anyone had this problem even with administrator privileges on Windows? The files aren`t being used by any other processes, I disabled my antivirus. Nothing worked.
C:\Windows\System32>npm i -g @nestjs/cli
npm WARN deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\cli',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@nestjs\cli\node_modules\typescript\lib'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\cli\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\cli',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@nestjs\cli\node_modules\rxjs\dist\esm5\internal'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\cli\\node_modules\\rxjs\\dist\\esm5\\internal'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\nest.ps1
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\nest.ps1'
npm ERR!     at async open (node:internal/fs/promises:638:25)
npm ERR!     at async writeFile (node:internal/fs/promises:1221:14)
npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm ERR!     at async #createBinLinks (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\rebuild.js:398:5)
npm ERR!     at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
npm ERR!     at async #linkAllBins (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\rebuild.js:379:5)
npm ERR!     at async #build (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\rebuild.js:163:7)
npm ERR!     at async Arborist.rebuild (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\rebuild.js:65:5)
npm ERR!  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\nest.ps1'
npm ERR!     at async open (node:internal/fs/promises:638:25)
npm ERR!     at async writeFile (node:internal/fs/promises:1221:14)
npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm ERR!     at async #createBinLinks (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\rebuild.js:398:5)
npm ERR!     at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
npm ERR!     at async #linkAllBins (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\rebuild.js:379:5)
npm ERR!     at async #build (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\rebuild.js:163:7)
npm ERR!     at async Arborist.rebuild (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\rebuild.js:65:5) {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\nest.ps1'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

For more context:
When i run corepack enable (it is not just on npm install) i get the same permission error (EPERM). This makes me unable to install yarn, for example.
I tried:

Run as Administrator (both cmd and powershell)
Disable Antivirus
Restart computer
Reinstall NODE.js

All expecting that it would run the command fine. Nothing worked

You do not need install -g: just install the tools you need in the dir you need them, and then run them either using npx on the command line, or without any special additionals in your scripts section of package.json. In this case, just install it normally, then run the nestjs CLI too using npx .... (which comes with Node.js, just like npm does). Having said that: read the error message because it's literally telling you not to use one of the dependencies, which means you need to check the nestjs issue tracker to see whether anyone's reported this, and what your options are.

perhaps you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am following the recommended method of installation of nest.js, please check: https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/overview. I have read the error message, still that does not solve my problem, nestjs is just an example. If i try to install any module globally (which I honestly need) it will fail for permission reasons, even when i run as admin. As for when i run corepack enable (I can`t install yarn... for this reason) I get EPERM ERROR, just the same. Leading me to the conclusion the problem is in my system, even though i seem to have all permissions.

@SaadQureshi The method shown on the answers did not work for me.

Any recommendation to use npm install -g is an outdated recommendation from before Node came with npx and 100% not needed. Not even "honestly": never install anything globally, just install it locally to your project (which does not require any sudo or Windows UAC admin rights) and then use npx to run that on the command line (or directly without npx when writing an npm script entry in your package.json).

(Also, you should never need admin rights for Node dependencies, because once an install has admin rights, it can do anything it likes to your computer, from harvesting your data to formatting your harddisk due to postinstall hooks. Install things locally: ever since npx got bundled into Node itself, npm install -g has been obsolete. It's just a security hole you should stay far away from)

But as a final comment: I can't reproduce this. If I run npm install @nestjs/cli (no -g) on Windows 10 with Node 21, which is the current version, I get none of the logs you show. It just installs, and running npx @nestjs/cli afterwards runs the cli tool and prints the help output, exactly as one would expect.

npm install @nestjs/cli, doing only will install it locally and cli commands will not be available globally, to use commands you'll have to do npx nest ...
How did you install the nodejs?
Have you tried using nvm?
if your main purpose is to start work using npm then there are plenty of workarounds you can use docker and you can install linux for windows but I am sure installing node from nvm will fix your problems.

(I tend to not recommend Docker for day-to-day development purposes.)
