# "npm install" fails on networked drive but runs local

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I have a smaller nodejs project I recently wanted to work on again on a new setup windows 10 pc. As I had a network drive on a Synology NAS as home directory I preferred to have my git projects laying on that mirrored and backuped drive.

A npm install currectly gives that **error 4048 EPERM** and **4082 EBUSY** message:

```
H:\git\iplog>npm install
npm WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'H:\git\iplog\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\dashdash\node_modules'
npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'H:\git\iplog\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\dashdash\node_modules'
npm WARN   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir \'H:\\git\\iplog\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\dashdash\\node_modules\'',
npm WARN   errno: -4048,
npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN   syscall: 'scandir',
npm WARN   path: 'H:\\git\\iplog\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\dashdash\\node_modules' }
npm ERR! path H:\git\iplog\node_modules\mjml-utils\src\mjml-utils.js.44668548
npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! errno -4082
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'H:\git\iplog\node_modules\mjml-utils\src\mjml-utils.js.44668548' -> 'H:\git\iplog\node_modules\mjml-utils\src\mjml-utils.js'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kai\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-02T08_54_06_379Z-debug.log
```

When I copy the complete project to my c: drive it works perfectly. Even the permissions on the networked drive seem to be OK, because all folders and files belong to my network account.

Nodejs is the current LTS version and gives

```
H:\git\iplog>npm version
{ Iplog: '0.0.3',
  npm: '5.5.1',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  cldr: '31.0.1',
  http_parser: '2.7.0',
  icu: '59.1',
  modules: '57',
  nghttp2: '1.25.0',
  node: '8.9.3',
  openssl: '1.0.2n',
  tz: '2017b',
  unicode: '9.0',
  uv: '1.15.0',
  v8: '6.1.534.48',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

Other commands like "npm cache clean" didn't help. No anti virus in the way. Just the Synonogy NAS as only difference.
I didn't found any similar matching problem within stackoverflow while searching.

Comment: Please visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860795/fail-to-install-npm-package-npm-err-errno-4048) possible duplicate

Comment: I already saw that question but I don't think it is a plain duplicate. Just downgrading from a supported LTS version can't be a solution and no tools are open while running that install command, so not a full duplicat ematch, just the same problem.

Comment: Which version of NPM and Node are you using (`node -v`, `npm -v`)?And what server are you using?

Comment: Have you at least tried the options in the answers to that question? You don’t even have the version of npm recommended in there (5.6.2)

Comment: npm as given above is version 5.5.1, node gives 8.9.3

Comment: @jcaron I want to stay with LTS versions, otherwise I would have more work updating the current versions to keep current. So the 5.5.1 for npm seems a stable starting point for me. But even upgrading to 5.6.0 makes no difference as I just tried out.