# I cannot create angular project with "ng new app_name". Get error -4058

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

When I execute the command `ng new app-name` I get error `-4058`.

When I run the same command opening cmd as administrator in the directory `C: / Windows/system32` I have no problems when creating the project. But if I change the directory I have the same issue.

I suppose it must be a permissions problem but it is not solved by opening `cmd` as administrator.

The creation process is frozen in `extract: rxjs:` and after a long time I get the following error

> npm ERR! path C:\Users\Usuario\proyectName\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT
>   npm ERR! errno -4058
>   npm ERR! syscall rename
>   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Usuario\proyectName\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript' -> 'C:\Users\Usuario\proyectName\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules.typescript.DELETE'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-03-20T02_40_45_377Z-debug.log
>   Error: Package install failed, see above.
>   Package install failed, see above.

Npm version

```
5.7.1
```

Angular version

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 8.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...
```

Comment: if you are behind any proxy please check your `.npmrc` file which in present in your user/home and check the entry for proxy and https-proxy . also you can disable strict-ssl by `strict-ssl=false`

Comment: I don't user any proxy.

Comment: then it seems it is some permission issue which is locking your current instance. Please refer [Fail to install npm package “npm ERR! errno -4048”
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860795/fail-to-install-npm-package-npm-err-errno-4048/31327161)

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by uninstalling completely angular / cli and node. After that, reinstall the node (not as administrator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by uninstalling completely angular/cli and node

1. Uninstalling angular/cli and nodejs as administrator.
2. Delete folders from% appdata% (npm, npm-cache)
3. delete "nodejs" folder from Programs and Files
4. Reboot
5. Reintall lastest version node (not as administrator)
6. Install angular/cli (not as administrator)