# Error -4048 while running 'npx cap add android'

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I have ionic 4 cordova app. I integrated with Capacitor. Now I am trying to add Android platform and I am getting below error:
[image: Terminal image]

I didn't found any relevant solution on web.

Comment: check the permissions on the project directory

Answer (score 1):

try

> npm cache verify

if this doesn't work

> npm cache clean --force

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860795/fail-to-install-npm-package-npm-err-errno-4048)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to add capacitor to existing project. Try removing unsupported Cordova plugins, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution to this problem. Just uninstall Cordova plugins which are not supported by Capacitor. Then Add Android. Here is the list of unsupported plugins https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/cordova/known-incompatible-plugins/