# Installing package from github not working

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, package

I'm trying to install a package from github for a react app using command:

```
npm install git+https://github.com/seyedmahdii/ckeditor5.git
```

But it runs into this error:

```
npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! syscall rmdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\seyed mahdi jalali\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-a036a193
npm ERR! errno -4082
npm ERR! EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'C:\Users\seyed mahdi jalali\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-a036a193'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\seyed mahdi jalali\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-19T05_54_51_099Z-debug.log
PS E:\mahdi\programming\projects\Tikkaa\next> npm install git+https://github.com/seyedmahdii/ckeditor5.git
npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! syscall rmdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\seyed mahdi jalali\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-78dc61ae
npm ERR! errno -4082
npm ERR! EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'C:\Users\seyed mahdi jalali\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-78dc61ae'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\seyed mahdi jalali\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-19T05_59_15_530Z-debug.log
```

I tried cleaning the cache, deleting node_modules, and using VPN.

This error is not just for installing this specific package. I can't install package from github at all. Installing from npm is ok.

thanks for any help.

Comment: please try it: Close Editor Software

Then Try again

Comment: Tried that before. Not working

Comment: This may bring you closer to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860795/fail-to-install-npm-package-npm-err-errno-4048