Not able to install mongodb -operation not permitted
I don't know why I have so many issues when I tried to install Mongodb.
I wanted to setup a project with Payload. I'm stuck when I want to connect my database mongodb. I tried to link directly the database using the string of connection in the env. file. But still the issue remains and I have an error telling me than MongoDB can't connect. Everything is settled on mongodb (I create the database and users).
this is the code I have :
npm install mongodb@6.9

npm error code EPERM
npm error syscall mkdir
npm error path C:\Users\Mila\node_modules\.corepack-2p9oARN1
npm error errno -4048
npm error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Mila\node_modules\.corepack-2p9oARN1'
npm error     at async Object.mkdir (node:internal/fs/promises:858:10)
npm error     at async moveFile (C:\Users\Mila\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\fs\lib\move-file.js:27:3)
npm error     at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm error     at async moveFile (C:\Users\Mila\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\fs\lib\move-file.js:36:9)
npm error     at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
npm error     at async [reifyPackages] (C:\Users\Mila\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:325:11)
npm error     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Users\Mila\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:142:5)
npm error     at async Install.exec (C:\Users\Mila\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:150:5)
npm error     at async Npm.exec (C:\Users\Mila\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:207:9)
npm error     at async module.exports (C:\Users\Mila\node_modules\npm\lib\cli\entry.js:74:5) {
npm error   errno: -4048,
npm error   code: 'EPERM',
npm error   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm error   path: 'C:\\Users\\Mila\\node_modules\\.corepack-2p9oARN1'
npm error }
npm error
npm error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm error It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm error or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm error
npm error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm error the command again as root/Administrator.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Mila\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-25T17_22_42_767Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\Mila\Desktop\Programs Project\PayloadEcom>


Have you got any suggestion, please ?


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/BhJ3ICzu.png


Do any of the answers from here help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860795/fail-to-install-npm-package-npm-err-errno-4048
